# Jquery Autocomplete issue in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working on a jquery mobile project which needs jquery autocomplete for forms. Due to some scrolling issue of autocomplete menu on mobile browser(which i'm not able to scroll on the mobile browser), I decided to use JScrollPane.js to implement custom scroller to my autocomplete menu, And successfully I have implemented the scroller for autocomplete, But now the issue is, the scrollbar works only for the first search,
  For ex: when i type 'a' it shows all the results for 'a' with custom scrollbar anu menu is scrollable, but again when i type 's', the custom scrollbar disappears and we cannot scroll the contents of autocomplete menu...

http://jsfiddle.net/uXbKY/2/

The same problem occurs for all consequent searches after first search, Is that a issue in Jquery or do i need any code change?

Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks in advance..